# How to Get JSON URL File and Have it Constantly Updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I am trying to continuously pull from a URL using the $.getJSON method and I am curious to know how to constantly pull that data and replace the existing data in html. I have read the documentation on this method on JQuery but I'm not sure if it will continuously update without having to refresh the page.

I have something like this

```
<script>
    .getJSON(""http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true", function(data) {
var address = json.results[0].formatted_address;
$('#address').text(address);
</script>
<html>
<p id="address"></p>
</html>
```

If someone can help me and get it where if the data is changing that the page will also change alongside that, that would be great.

Comment: it won't automatically update. `getJSON` simply gets the file and returns the object it represents. It won't get it over and over again, you'll have to setup a script to fetch the json again ever few seconds and update the page

Comment: @Markasoftware can you tell me how I would go about doing that? Would I use the setTimeOut method? Any suggestions?

Comment: setInterval is the standard way, look at @ChrisFritz's answer

Comment: @Markasoftware thanks for the help Mark. Do you know how to set the beginning interval to first run so the first run isn't dependent on waiting 5 seconds?

Comment: yes, you should have a function that does the task. Then, run the function right away, then have a setInterval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encapsulate that code in something like this:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  // stuff I want to run every 5 seconds
}, 5000);
```

Then every 5000 milliseconds (i.e. 5 seconds), it'll fetch new JSON and replace the current address with the new address.

Comment: Chris my question is how to would you get this to run in the beginning duration since I have to wait 5 seconds before it actually updates.

Comment: If you place that code in a function, you can run the function when the page loads and then also call that function within `setInterval`.

Comment: would that be a better option that just calling the function and then run the setinterval on it right afterwards?

Comment: I don't think I understand the difference between what I said and what you just said. Can you please clarify?

Comment: right, we are on the same terms then. Is there any way to know that its updating? So can you store the previous data in a variable and compare that to when it runs again with setInterval?